# Hosting Docker containers using IIS

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a windows 10 pc which is used to host my websites, now I installed docker desktop and i would like to host my one container using IIS if possible, now how do i set the physical path when I am creating a website on iis to use this docker container? Is this possible to do? Which other method should I use to host my docker sites but at the same time keep my iis sites which are already hosted stay online?
My Docker is installed with WSL 2 based engine and when i go to `docker info` i get the following: `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker`

Comment: I'm living in world of linux but AFIK IIS works as reverse proxy too. So you can expose container port and then let IIS to route all requests to this port

Comment: @Facty The thing with iis is that it needs you to enter a physical path to the directory, i have exposed the port and tried to route it that way but it wasnt working

Comment: Well then you are setting (called in linux world) virtual machine. What you have to setup is fully featured reverse proxy. To be honest I'm not interested in reading whole MS documentation on IIS but [THIS](https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/AdminGuide/Hardening/RevProxy_IIS.htm) manual how to setup IIS Reverse Proxy might help you or you can find more on internet

Comment: @Facty This will help, Thank you so much!